# Remember Tab in Tab position on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following problem.
In bootstrap i have Tab/Pill menu:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="nav nav-tabs flex-column nav-pills" id="myTab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
                <a class="nav-link" id="settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">

            <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">...</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and JS script like this:

```
<script>
    // Javascript to enable link to tab
    var url = document.location.toString();
    if (url.match('#')) {
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
    }

    // Change hash for page-reload
    $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
    })
</script>
```

It work fine, but I want something like tab in tab.

I have:

[image: Tab1]

but I want work something like this:

[image: TabinTab]

and when i open tab "Profile Tab 2" in new windows it's not working.

Comment: You need a more complex hash something like `#main_tab/secondary_tab`

Comment: Do you know how to get something like that? I'm unfortunately nooby in JS.